# How to get tpl files highlighted in pycharm?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, bottle

What file association will get the correct highlighting for *.tpl files in Pycharm? I have tried HTML and PHP, but neither seem to get it 100%.

I am using bottle and python 2.7 on a Windows machine.

Comment: It doesn't do CSS files either.

Comment: There is a relevant issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835876/bottle-template-support/25836733#25836733.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: original image]

Just setting it like the picture:

Choose Editor -> File Types -> Recognized File Types -> HTML

Add a Registered Patterns: *.tpl

Your question will be solved.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. You can increase the quality of your answer, by also adding a textual explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I'll increase the quality of this answer.