# Bottle Template Support?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, bottle

I'm using PyCharm 3.4.1 and learning MongoDB from Mongo University.  In the code, they have us using Python to create html pages using the MVC pattern with bottle.

When I add a file of type .tpl to the editor in PyCharm, there is no "intellisense" or support for the model in the code.  Changing it to be in the list of html file types helps some, but no python support in the editor.

Is there a plugin or some other change i can make to support editing better?  Seems someone else asked something similar earlier in the year at [How to get tpl files highlighted in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555842/how-to-get-tpl-files-highlighted-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottle comes with a built-in template engine called [`SimpleTemplate`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html) which [is not currently supported by PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/python-template-languages.html).

There is a relevant feature request: [`Bottle microframework support`](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4642), but it doesn't explicitly state about `.tpl` syntax support.

I'd go and create a feature request in [PyCharm's issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) asking about `SimpleTemplate` syntax support or, at least, vote up and comment in the existing issue.

For example, there is the similar feature-request for `tornado` template engine:

- [Add Tornado Template Support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1706#tab=Comments)

It has currently 56 votes up which is probably increasing the possibility of seeing it happen.

---

As a workaround, you can configure `.tpl` file type under [`Settings -> File Types`](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-and-registering-file-types.html). It is possible to set highlighting rules there.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get highlighting to show me HTML, but it didn't really work for the python code i added.